# Remove GUI on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, gui

I installed a GUI on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS using
`sudo aptitude install --without-recommends ubuntu-desktop`
not sure why just playing around. Any way I would like to remove it and cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It should be as easy as telling apt you want to remove Xorg and it will trigger removal of all the packages which depend on X.

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-core
```

Just in case that doesn't work, here is a list of everything which ubuntu-desktop triggers to be installed on my bare ubuntu-server install:

```
account-plugin-aim account-plugin-facebook account-plugin-flickr
  account-plugin-google account-plugin-icons account-plugin-identica
  account-plugin-jabber account-plugin-salut account-plugin-twitter
  account-plugin-windows-live account-plugin-yahoo acl acpi-support acpid
  activity-log-manager-common activity-log-manager-control-center
  adium-theme-ubuntu aisleriot alsa-base alsa-utils anacron apg
  app-install-data app-install-data-partner appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3
  appmenu-qt apport apport-gtk apport-symptoms aptdaemon aptdaemon-data apturl
  apturl-common aspell aspell-en at-spi2-core avahi-autoipd avahi-daemon
  avahi-utils bamfdaemon baobab bc binutils bluez bluez-alsa bluez-cups
  bluez-gstreamer branding-ubuntu brasero brasero-cdrkit brasero-common brltty
  checkbox checkbox-qt colord compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome
  compiz-plugins-default consolekit cpp cpp-4.7 cracklib-runtime
  cryptsetup-bin cups cups-bsd cups-client cups-common cups-filters cups-ppdc
  dbus-x11 dc dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service dconf-tools deja-dup
  desktop-file-utils dictionaries-common diffstat dmz-cursor-theme
  dnsmasq-base doc-base duplicity dvd+rw-tools empathy empathy-common enchant
  eog espeak-data evince evince-common evolution-data-server
  evolution-data-server-common example-content file-roller firefox
  firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support folks-common fontconfig
  fontconfig-config fonts-freefont-ttf fonts-kacst fonts-kacst-one
  fonts-khmeros-core fonts-lao fonts-liberation fonts-lklug-sinhala
  fonts-nanum fonts-opensymbol fonts-sil-abyssinica fonts-sil-padauk
  fonts-takao-pgothic fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-tibetan-machine fonts-tlwg-garuda
  fonts-tlwg-kinnari fonts-tlwg-loma fonts-tlwg-mono fonts-tlwg-norasi
  fonts-tlwg-purisa fonts-tlwg-sawasdee fonts-tlwg-typewriter
  fonts-tlwg-typist fonts-tlwg-typo fonts-tlwg-umpush fonts-tlwg-waree
  foomatic-db-compressed-ppds foomatic-db-engine foomatic-filters freerdp-x11
  gcalctool gcc gcc-4.7 gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2
  gconf2-common gcr gdb gedit gedit-common genisoimage geoclue
  geoclue-ubuntu-geoip gettext ghostscript ghostscript-cups ghostscript-x
  gir1.2-accounts-1.0 gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-atspi-2.0
  gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4 gir1.2-dee-1.0 gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gdata-0.0
  gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0
  gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-0.10
  gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-gudev-1.0
  gir1.2-indicate-0.7 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 gir1.2-messagingmenu-1.0
  gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0
  gir1.2-signon-1.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-syncmenu-0.1 gir1.2-totem-1.0
  gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0 gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 gir1.2-unity-5.0
  gir1.2-vte-2.90 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 gksu glib-networking
  glib-networking-common glib-networking-services gnome-accessibility-themes
  gnome-bluetooth gnome-contacts gnome-control-center
  gnome-control-center-data gnome-control-center-signon gnome-desktop3-data
  gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer gnome-games-data gnome-icon-theme
  gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-keyring gnome-mahjongg gnome-media
  gnome-menus gnome-online-accounts gnome-orca gnome-power-manager
  gnome-screensaver gnome-screenshot gnome-session gnome-session-bin
  gnome-session-canberra gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon
  gnome-sudoku gnome-system-log gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal
  gnome-terminal-data gnome-user-guide gnome-user-share gnomine growisofs
  gsettings-desktop-schemas gsfonts gstreamer0.10-alsa gstreamer0.10-gconf
  gstreamer0.10-nice gstreamer0.10-plugins-base
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
  gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio gstreamer0.10-tools gstreamer0.10-x gtk2-engines
  gtk2-engines-murrine gtk3-engines-unico gucharmap guile-1.8-libs gvfs
  gvfs-backends gvfs-bin gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse gvfs-libs gwibber
  gwibber-service gwibber-service-facebook gwibber-service-identica
  gwibber-service-twitter hardening-includes hicolor-icon-theme hpijs hplip
  hplip-data humanity-icon-theme hunspell-en-us hwdata ibus ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3
  ibus-pinyin ibus-pinyin-db-android ibus-pinyin-db-open-phrase ibus-table
  im-switch indicator-applet indicator-application indicator-appmenu
  indicator-datetime indicator-messages indicator-power indicator-printers
  indicator-session indicator-sound inputattach intel-gpu-tools
  intltool-debian iputils-arping kerneloops-daemon landscape-client-ui-install
  language-selector-gnome libaa1 libaccount-plugin-1.0-0 libaccounts-glib0
  libaccounts-qt1 libappindicator1 libappindicator3-1 libapt-pkg-perl
  libarchive-zip-perl libarchive12 libart-2.0-2 libasound2 libasound2-plugins
  libaspell15 libasyncns0 libatasmart4 libatk-adaptor libatk-adaptor-data
  libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatkmm-1.6-1 libatspi2.0-0
  libaudio2 libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3
  libavahi-core7 libavahi-glib1 libavahi-gobject0 libavc1394-0 libbamf3-0
  libbluetooth3 libboost-date-time1.49.0 libbrasero-media3-1 libbrlapi0.5
  libburn4 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcaca0 libcairo-gobject2 libcairo-perl
  libcairo2 libcairomm-1.0-1 libcamel-1.2-40 libcanberra-gtk-module
  libcanberra-gtk0 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module
  libcanberra-pulse libcanberra0 libcap2 libcap2-bin libcdio-cdda1
  libcdio-paranoia1 libcdio13 libcdparanoia0 libck-connector0 libclone-perl
  libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common libclutter-gst-1.0-0
  libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcmis-0.2-2 libcogl-common libcogl-pango0 libcogl9
  libcolord1 libcompizconfig0 libcrack2 libcroco3 libcrypt-passwdmd5-perl
  libcryptsetup4 libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2
  libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libcurl3 libcurl3-nss libdaemon0 libdatrie1
  libdbusmenu-glib4 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 libdbusmenu-gtk4 libdbusmenu-qt2
  libdconf1 libdecoration0 libdee-1.0-4 libdevmapper-event1.02.1
  libdigest-hmac-perl libdiscid0 libdjvulibre-text libdjvulibre21
  libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libdotconf1.0 libdpkg-perl libdrm-nouveau2 libdv4
  libebackend-1.2-5 libebook-1.2-14 libecal-1.2-15 libedata-book-1.2-15
  libedata-cal-1.2-18 libedataserver-1.2-17 libemail-valid-perl libenchant1c2a
  libespeak1 libevdocument3-4 libevview3-3 libexempi3 libexif12 libexiv2-12
  libexttextcat-1.0-0 libexttextcat-data libfarstream-0.1-0
  libfile-basedir-perl libfile-copy-recursive-perl libfile-desktopentry-perl
  libfile-fcntllock-perl libfile-mimeinfo-perl libflac8 libfolks-eds25
  libfolks-telepathy25 libfolks25 libfontconfig1 libfontembed1 libfontenc1
  libframe6 libfreerdp-plugins-standard libfreerdp1 libfs6 libgail-3-0
  libgail-common libgail18 libgck-1-0 libgconf-2-4 libgcr-3-1 libgcr-3-common
  libgd2-xpm libgdata-common libgdata13 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgee2 libgeis1 libgeoclue0 libgettextpo0
  libgexiv2-1 libgksu2-0 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa
  libglew1.8 libglewmx1.8 libglib-perl libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin
  libglib2.0-data libglibmm-2.4-1c2a libglu1-mesa libgmime-2.6-0 libgmp10
  libgnome-bluetooth11 libgnome-control-center1 libgnome-desktop-3-4
  libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-keyring0 libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0
  libgnome-menu-3-0 libgnome-menu2 libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd8
  libgoa-1.0-0 libgoa-1.0-common libgomp1 libgpgme11 libgphoto2-2
  libgphoto2-l10n libgphoto2-port0 libgpod-common libgpod4 libgrail5 libgrip0
  libgs9 libgs9-common libgssdp-1.0-3 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
  libgstreamer0.10-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk2-perl
  libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common libgtkmm-3.0-1
  libgtksourceview-3.0-0 libgtksourceview-3.0-common libgtkspell-3-0
  libgtop2-7 libgtop2-common libgucharmap-2-90-7 libgudev-1.0-0 libgupnp-1.0-4
  libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 libgusb2 libgutenprint2 libgweather-3-1
  libgweather-common libgwibber-gtk3 libgwibber3 libgxps2 libhpmud0
  libhunspell-1.3-0 libhyphen0 libibus-1.0-0 libical0 libice6 libicu48
  libido3-0.1-0 libiec61883-0 libieee1284-3 libijs-0.35 libimobiledevice3
  libindicate5 libindicator3-7 libindicator7 libio-pty-perl
  libio-socket-inet6-perl libipc-run-perl libisofs6 libitm1 libiw30
  libjack-jackd2-0 libjasper1 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjbig0 libjbig2dec0
  libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libjs-jquery libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson0 libjte1
  libkpathsea6 liblcms1 liblcms2-2 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblircclient0
  libllvm3.1 liblouis-data liblouis2 libltdl7 liblua5.1-0 liblvm2app2.2
  libmailtools-perl libmeanwhile1 libmessaging-menu0 libmetacity-private0a
  libmhash2 libminiupnpc8 libmission-control-plugins0 libmng1 libmpc2 libmpfr4
  libmtdev1 libmtp-common libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libmusicbrainz5-0 libmx-1.0-2
  libmx-bin libmx-common libmysqlclient18 libmythes-1.2-0 libnatpmp1
  libnautilus-extension1a libneon27-gnutls libnet-dns-perl
  libnet-domain-tld-perl libnet-ip-perl libnetfilter-conntrack3 libnettle4
  libnice10 libnl-route-3-200 libnm-glib-vpn1 libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk-common
  libnm-gtk0 libnm-util2 libnotify-bin libnotify4 libnspr4 libnss-mdns libnss3
  libnux-3.0-0 libnux-3.0-common liboauth0 libogg0 libopencc1 libopenobex1
  liborc-0.4-0 libpackagekit-glib2-14 libpam-cap libpam-ck-connector
  libpam-freerdp libpam-gnome-keyring libpam-xdg-support libpanel-applet-4-0
  libpango-perl libpango1.0-0 libpangomm-1.4-1 libpaper-utils libpaper1
  libpcsclite1 libpeas-1.0-0 libpeas-common libperl5.14 libpixman-1-0
  libplist1 libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-backend-1-0 libpoppler-glib8
  libpoppler28 libportaudio2 libprotobuf7 libprotoc7 libproxy1
  libproxy1-plugin-gsettings libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager libpth20
  libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulsedsp libpurple-bin libpurple0
  libpwquality1 libpython3.2 libqjson0 libqpdf8 libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative
  libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-network libqt4-script libqt4-scripttools
  libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-test
  libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtassistantclient4 libqtcore4 libqtgui4
  libqtwebkit4 libquadmath0 libquvi-scripts libquvi7 libraptor2-0 librasqal3
  libraw1394-11 libraw5 librdf0 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc
  libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-emailmerge
  libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress
  libreoffice-math libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport
  libreoffice-presentation-minimizer libreoffice-presenter-console
  libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer
  librest-0.7-0 librhythmbox-core6 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common librsync1
  libsamplerate0 libsane libsane-common libsane-hpaio libsecret-1-0
  libsecret-common libsensors4 libsgutils2-2 libshout3 libsignon-extension1
  libsignon-glib1 libsignon-plugins-common1 libsignon-qt1 libsm6 libsmbclient
  libsndfile1 libsnmp-base libsnmp15 libsocket6-perl libsonic0
  libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libspectre1 libspeechd2 libspeex1
  libspeexdsp1 libssh-4 libstartup-notification0 libsync-menu1
  libsyncdaemon-1.0-1 libsysfs2 libt1-5 libtag1-vanilla libtag1c2a libtalloc2
  libtdb1 libtelepathy-farstream2 libtelepathy-glib0 libtelepathy-logger2
  libthai-data libthai0 libtheora0 libtiff5 libtimezonemap1
  libtotem-plparser17 libtotem0 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 libubuntuoneui-3.0-1
  libudisks2-0 libufe-xidgetter0 libunistring0 libunity-core-6.0-5
  libunity-misc4 libunity-protocol-private0 libunity-webapps0 libunity9
  libupower-glib1 liburi-perl libusbmuxd2 libutempter0 libuuid-perl libv4l-0
  libv4lconvert0 libvisual-0.4-0 libvisual-0.4-plugins libvncserver0
  libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libvorbisfile3 libvte-2.90-9 libvte-2.90-common
  libwacom-common libwacom2 libwavpack1 libwbclient0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libwhoopsie0 libwmf0.2-7 libwmf0.2-7-gtk libwnck-3-0
  libwnck-3-common libwnck-common libwnck22 libwpd-0.9-9 libwpg-0.2-2
  libwps-0.2-2 libx11-xcb1 libx86-1 libxatracker1 libxaw7 libxcb-dri2-0
  libxcb-glx0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-util0
  libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxfont1 libxft2 libxi6
  libxinerama1 libxkbfile1 libxklavier16 libxml2 libxmu6 libxp6 libxpm4
  libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxres1 libxslt1.1 libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1 libxvmc1
  libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1 libyajl2 libyaml-tiny-perl libyelp0
  libzeitgeist-1.0-1 libzephyr4 light-themes lightdm
  lightdm-remote-session-freerdp lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure lintian
  linux-libc-dev linux-sound-base make manpages-dev mcp-account-manager-uoa
  media-player-info metacity-common mobile-broadband-provider-info
  modemmanager mousetweaks mscompress mtools mysql-common nautilus
  nautilus-data nautilus-sendto nautilus-sendto-empathy nautilus-share
  network-manager network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp
  network-manager-pptp-gnome notification-daemon notify-osd notify-osd-icons
  nux-tools obex-data-server obexd-client onboard oneconf openprinting-ppds
  overlay-scrollbar overlay-scrollbar-gtk2 overlay-scrollbar-gtk3 patch
  patchutils pcmciautils perl perl-base perl-modules pinyin-database
  pkg-config plymouth-label plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo pm-utils policykit-1
  policykit-1-gnome policykit-desktop-privileges poppler-data poppler-utils
  pptp-linux printer-driver-c2esp printer-driver-foo2zjs
  printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-hpijs
  printer-driver-min12xxw printer-driver-pnm2ppa printer-driver-postscript-hp
  printer-driver-ptouch printer-driver-pxljr printer-driver-sag-gdi
  printer-driver-splix protobuf-compiler pulseaudio
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-gconf pulseaudio-module-x11
  pulseaudio-utils python-appindicator python-apport python-aptdaemon
  python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-cairo python-configglue python-cups
  python-cupshelpers python-dbus python-dbus-dev python-debtagshw python-defer
  python-dirspec python-gconf python-gi python-gi-cairo python-gnomekeyring
  python-gnupginterface python-gobject python-gobject-2 python-gst0.10
  python-gtk2 python-httplib2 python-ibus python-imaging python-libxml2
  python-lxml python-mako python-markupsafe python-notify python-oauth
  python-openssl python-pam python-pexpect python-piston-mini-client
  python-pkg-resources python-problem-report python-protobuf python-pycurl
  python-pyinotify python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus python-renderpm python-reportlab
  python-reportlab-accel python-serial python-simplejson python-sip
  python-smbc python-twisted-bin python-twisted-core python-twisted-names
  python-twisted-web python-ubuntu-sso-client python-ubuntuone-client
  python-ubuntuone-control-panel python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol python-uno
  python-xdg python-zeitgeist python-zope.interface python3-apport
  python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat
  python3-brlapi python3-cairo python3-crypto python3-defer
  python3-distupgrade python3-gi-cairo python3-httplib2 python3-louis
  python3-lxml python3-oauthlib python3-pkg-resources python3-problem-report
  python3-pyatspi2 python3-pycurl python3-software-properties python3-speechd
  python3-update-manager python3-virtkey python3-xdg python3-xkit python3.2
  python3.2-minimal qdbus qpdf qt-at-spi radeontool remmina remmina-common
  remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-vnc remote-login-service rfkill rhythmbox
  rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-mozilla rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder
  rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins
  rhythmbox-ubuntuone rtkit samba-common samba-common-bin sane-utils seahorse
  session-migration sessioninstaller sgml-base shared-mime-info shotwell
  signon-keyring-extension signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-plugin-password
  signon-ui signond simple-scan smbclient sni-qt software-center
  software-center-aptdaemon-plugins software-properties-common
  software-properties-gtk sound-theme-freedesktop speech-dispatcher
  ssh-askpass-gnome ssl-cert syslinux syslinux-common syslinux-legacy
  system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-gnome
  system-config-printer-udev telepathy-gabble telepathy-haze telepathy-idle
  telepathy-indicator telepathy-logger telepathy-mission-control-5
  telepathy-salut thin-client-config-agent thunderbird thunderbird-globalmenu
  thunderbird-gnome-support toshset totem totem-common totem-mozilla
  totem-plugins transmission-common transmission-gtk ttf-dejavu-core
  ttf-indic-fonts-core ttf-punjabi-fonts ttf-ubuntu-font-family
  ttf-wqy-microhei ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-docs ubuntu-drivers-common
  ubuntu-extras-keyring ubuntu-mono ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-settings ubuntu-sounds ubuntu-sso-client
  ubuntu-sso-client-qt ubuntu-system-service ubuntu-wallpapers
  ubuntu-wallpapers-quantal ubuntuone-client ubuntuone-client-gnome
  ubuntuone-control-panel ubuntuone-control-panel-qt ubuntuone-couch udisks
  udisks2 unattended-upgrades unity unity-asset-pool unity-common
  unity-greeter unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-gwibber
  unity-lens-music unity-lens-photos unity-lens-shopping unity-lens-video
  unity-scope-gdocs unity-scope-musicstores unity-scope-video-remote
  unity-services unity-webapps-common unity-webapps-service uno-libs3 unzip
  update-inetd update-manager update-manager-core update-notifier
  update-notifier-common upower ure usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk
  usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data usbmuxd vbetool vino wamerican whoopsie
  wireless-tools wodim wpasupplicant x11-apps x11-common x11-session-utils
  x11-utils x11-xfs-utils x11-xkb-utils x11-xserver-utils xbitmaps
  xcursor-themes xdg-user-dirs xdg-user-dirs-gtk xdg-utils xdiagnose
  xfonts-base xfonts-encodings xfonts-mathml xfonts-scalable xfonts-utils
  xinit xinput xml-core xorg xorg-docs-core xserver-common xserver-xorg
  xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-evdev
  xserver-xorg-input-mouse xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
  xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all
  xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-cirrus xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
  xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-mach64 xserver-xorg-video-mga
  xserver-xorg-video-modesetting xserver-xorg-video-neomagic
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
  xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-r128 xserver-xorg-video-radeon
  xserver-xorg-video-s3 xserver-xorg-video-savage
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion xserver-xorg-video-sis
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb xserver-xorg-video-tdfx xserver-xorg-video-trident
  xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware xterm xul-ext-ubufox
  xul-ext-unity xul-ext-websites-integration yelp yelp-xsl zeitgeist
  zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub zenity zenity-common zip
```

You could copy and paste that into an apt-get remove command line.

Comment: The old girl decided to die and I had to recreate my server on another machine, therefore I never had a chance to try this. Thank you though. I didnt want to leave it hanging out there and I am nto sure what the protocol is to accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the list of packages.  I just tried removing all of those from a Saucy GUI install and it left it quite unable to boot.  Somehow, upstart among other things was removed.

Comment: This doesn't remove stuff like chromium browser, vlc etc

Comment: apt-get remove --purge x11-common && apt-get autoremove  this will

Answer (score 1):

Wrote a simple script to remove those packages.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for line in $(cat pkgdel.txt)
do
   apt-get remove $line -y
done
```

- create a text file called  `pkgdel.txt`
- copy & paste the package [list from this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/260462/527764)
- run the script...

Comment: I fail to see why I would want to do this. Using `for` will be extremely slow as it will run the command once for each argument. Fortunately packages are always named sanely afaik, but if they weren't, shell expansions and wordsplitting would cause unexpected behaviour too

Comment: just do `apt-get remove -y` followed by the list from the other answer and you’re done